# JavaFX label binding to integer value not changing

Tags: java, javafx

I am building a battleship game in javaFX. For the game I want to display 2 labels, which depict the number of ships the player and the computer have. However the number does not change. My code is the following:

The Main Class can be implemented with the following code:

```
  package sample;

import java.util.Random;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.IntegerProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleIntegerProperty;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.geometry.Rectangle2D;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.scene.layout.*;
import javafx.stage.Screen;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    private Board enemyBoard;

    private Random random = new Random();

    private Parent createContent() {
        BorderPane root = new BorderPane();
        root.setPrefSize(600, 800);

        EventHandler<ActionEvent> event1 = new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            public void handle(ActionEvent e)
            {
                enemyBoard.ships--;
            }
        };

        enemyBoard = new Board();

        Label label4 = new Label("Computer Ships Available: ");
        IntegerProperty eships = new SimpleIntegerProperty(enemyBoard.ships);
        label4.textProperty().bind(eships.asString());
        Button newb = new Button("Change");
        newb.setOnAction(event1);
        root.setCenter(label4);
        root.setBottom(newb);

        return (root);
    }


    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {

        Scene scene = new Scene(createContent());
        primaryStage.setTitle("Battleship");
        primaryStage.setResizable(false);


        primaryStage.setScene(scene);

        Rectangle2D primaryScreenBounds = Screen.getPrimary().getVisualBounds();

        //set Stage boundaries to visible bounds of the main screen

        primaryStage.setX(primaryScreenBounds.getMinX());
        primaryStage.setY(primaryScreenBounds.getMinY());
        primaryStage.setWidth(primaryScreenBounds.getWidth()-400);
        primaryStage.setHeight(primaryScreenBounds.getHeight()-100);

        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }


}
```

And the Board Class:

```
package sample;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.geometry.Point2D;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;

public class Board extends Parent{
    private VBox rows = new VBox();
    private boolean enemy  = false;
    public int ships = 5;
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: [mcve] please .. best _after_ working through a tutorial about how to use bindings in javafx (the last snippet won't even compile ..)

Comment: strip it down, nobody wants to wade through tons of unrelated code (like menus, fancy ui, custom items like player or such) - all you need in an example app is some IntegerProperty that you can change (f.i. by a button) and a label to bind.

Comment: .. and don't forget to work through a tutorial: you don't seem to have a clear understanding of the _concept_ of binding

Comment: repeating: a single label, a single integerProperty, a single button to modify the value of the integerProperty is all you need - write it (that's called a [mcve] is - be sure to read that help page as well :) Don't read/watch tons of tutorials - stick to one (f.i. one of the early oracle stuff, nothing changed) and _work_ through it: use the example in tutorial and play with it until you are confident you really _understand_ what it is doing.

Comment: @asimplecoder “all the other stuff is needed”. Seriously? Surely all you need to reproduce the problem is a label, a class with an integer held inside it, and a button that changes its value. No-one wants to go through all that code that’s irrelevant to what you’re asking. Start from scratch and add in *just enough* to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Exactly. You should create a new project to understand the problem. If the problem doesn’t occur in that simple example, you’re halfway to solving it. I do this 5 or 6 times every day. Does nobody teach troubleshooting any more?

Comment: @James_D I followed your advice, and still had the same problem. I edited the question with the simplest example. Thank you

Comment: @kleopatra I edited the question to be better, sorry for the trouble

Comment: OK, no time for. complete answer now, but the problem is that you never change the property (`eships`) to which the label is bound. You only change the `int` value. Your `Board` class needs to represent `ships` as an `IntegerProperty`, and then you bind to that property.

Comment: @James_D I did it, thank you! I will wait for you to write the answer so I can accept it.

Comment: congrats (and +1) for actually putting effort into climbing up the learning curve :)

Answer (score 0):

You aren't changing the property you've bound the label to.  Make the SimpleIntegerProperty accessible and change it.  Something like this:

```
    EventHandler<ActionEvent> event1 = new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
        public void handle(ActionEvent e)
        {
            eships.set(eships.get()-1);
        }
    };
```

You might also want to put the property in your enemyBoard class.  You don't need the raw int.

```
    EventHandler<ActionEvent> event1 = new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
        public void handle(ActionEvent e)
        {
            enemyBoard.ships.set(enemyBoard.ships.get()-1);
        }
    };
```

With:

```
public class Board extends Parent{
    private VBox rows = new VBox();
    private boolean enemy  = false;
    public SimpleintegerProperty ships = new SimpleIntegerProperty(5);
}
```